# How to strip off a final object(mesh) into many separate segments

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, transforms

I have a final mesh and whant strip off it to many separate objects, wanna create parametric furniture. I find video only for 3d max, they used Splines section, how to achieve the same result. Plz help, i broke my head.

Comment: you could use boolean to slice your object but it looks like you need to fill the holes it creates?

Comment: yea i need fill holes in objects

Comment: so have your tried the boolean method?

Comment: its not work for me. I need separate mulipl  objects from my final mesh, plz google parametric furniture u will see what i need, to my final mesh.

Comment: with boolean you will have separate meshes within your object, then you can make separate objects with each mesh with P (separate) > By Loose Parts. The only tedious part is to fill each surface of each mesh, maybe it's avoidable(?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it (I mean, if I understand correctly what you want). Note that you may have some bugs when you'll apply the Boolean, and you may have to fix your mesh (i.e. fill surfaces).

[image]

Comment: did it help? did you succeed?

Comment: yea i did this! thx!

Comment: @АЛИДЖА please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!